# Passing context.Context to all relevant methods, golang

Tags: go, logrus

I read all the decisions about dropping the ThreadLocal and I can relate.
Seems like passing around the `request.Context()` that is of type `context.Context` gives the ability to manage scoped services.

I am using `logrus` for logging and want to log a `requestId` that is a generate udid from a midlleware in `gin`

I know i can do something like this

```golang
func Authentication(conf Configuration, logger ILogger, cache ICacheService) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        logger := logrus.WithContext(c)
        c.Set("traceId", uuid.New().String())
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

And the pass around the entry or even store the entry inside the context whatever works, but...
I also have a `Redis` and `MongoDb` clients that are `singletons` and I am wrapping them with my own package to facilitate logging of any outgoing I\O requests.

because they are singletones I cannot pas the `context.Context` to the constructor but ill have to pass it to every method like `GetKey` `SetKet` etc..

any common patterns for using the context \ request id logging inside a Singleton service ?

Comment: The common pattern is to pass it to every method. Be explicit.

Comment: As Volker stated, you have to pass it to every method. In database/sql library of golang, all db methods have two versions one with context and another without context. Ex: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryContext

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way is to pass `context.Context` to every method. In fact, contexts are not supposed to be passed in constructors or stored as struct members. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/):

> Do not store Contexts inside a struct type; instead, pass a Context explicitly to each function that needs it.

Comment: I agree, what a user wants to add, it can be added from the caller function and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wrapping them with my own package to facilitate logging of any
>   outgoing I\O requests.

Libraries with good API design provide customization of transport functionality or possibly provide the ability to add hooks for such purposes with closure context making you possible to decorate them with logging. Redis should support custom dialers and you can inject your logging activity directly with closure function that get access both to context and to your logger, so no need to make wrapping if it was the only reason.

A cleaner software design is to instantiate logger once and pass it down to your dependencies. Context.Values are request scoped-values, not scoped services. Using dynamic context api for such purposes make your software very hard to predict, it will be better to utilize conveniences of strongly-typed API with Dependency Injection instead.

Hope it helps!